# Oracle add a virtual column which adds years

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

I'm trying to add a virtual column of date type which adds five years to another date column:

```
ALTER TABLE AU_Ventes ADD (
DateVente date NOT NULL,
DateFinGarantie date As(ADD_MONTHS(DateVente, 60))
);
```

But I get the error: "%s: invalid identifier". Perhaps I can't use the ADD_MONTHS function in an ALTER TABLE. What can I do to accomplish what I want to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can define a virtual column in a `create table` statement, where you are obviously creating it at the same time as the column it is based on, you can't define both in the same `alter table` statement. You have to do it in two steps:

```
ALTER TABLE AU_Ventes ADD DateVente date NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE AU_Ventes ADD DateFinGarantie date
  As(ADD_MONTHS(DateVente, 60));
```

Not sure that's an intentional restriction, but it's how it works.

[Trivial SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3256/1) to show this working.